# Powershell: Using Output from Get-ADComputer in Resolve-DNS

Tags: powershell

I frequently look up AD computer names by their description and I was hoping there was a way that I could take that output and put it into `Resolve-DNSName` to also get the IP address.

This is what I type in to get the computer name based on the AD Description:

```
$Description = Read-Host `n `n "Enter Description"
Get-ADComputer -Filter * -Properties Description |
    Where-Object { $_.Description -like $Description } |
    Format-Table Description,Name
```

This will give me the IP Address:

```
$PCNumber = Read-host "Computer Number"
Resolve-DnsName -Name $PCNumber | Format-Table IPAddress
```

Can I get guidance on how to put this together so I can enter the description and it will bring back the description and name, plus the IPAddress?

Comment: Please give some respect to punctuation marks

Comment: @IliaNedoluzhko Should be readable now.

Comment: Thanks! Keep your posts clean and welcome to SO!

Comment: Sorry first post I will do better

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way you're pulling the information from AD is really inefficient.
A best-practice mantra for the pipeline is: **Filter left, Format right**

```
$Description = Read-Host -Prompt 'Enter Description'

## $PC becomes a PSCustomObject with three properties
$PC = Get-ADComputer -Filter "Description -like '*$Description*'" -Properties Name,Description |
    Select-Object -Property @(
        'Name'
        'Description'
        @{ N = 'IPAddress'
           E = { (Resolve-DnsName -Name $_.Name).IPAddress }
         }
    )

$PC | Format-Table -Property Name,Description,IPAddress -Autosize
```

Comment: Your filter needs to be `-Filter "Description -like '*$Description*'"`.  Braces prevent the variable from expanding.  Also, you should avoid using `-Properties *` whenever possible.

Comment: @BaconBits I haven't had any issues with using script blocks in place of the `-Filter` parameter on the `ActiveDirectory` module. In fact, it's how I commonly see it done.  I was unsure of what properties he's trying to access or has on his computer objects, so I was being broad with the properties wildcard.

Comment: I agree in this case, he should probably use `-Properties Name,Description`

Comment: @BaconBits I see what you mean about the string expansion now. Updated my answer

Comment: Yeah, I've learned to avoid braces whenever the input is expecting a string.  Braces are only for script blocks.  What it's doing is casting a scriptblock to a string, and that doesn't do the same thing as evaluating a string.  They *never* should have put the braces in the documentation for the ActiveDirectory module.

Comment: @clr-tech Great. If my answer solved your question, kindly mark it as the answer with the green checkmark.

Answer (score 0):

`Get-ADComputer` has a property that is called `IPv4Address`. It's not an Active Directory attribute, but a property that is enumerated on execution. It basically does a DNS request, just like you did with `Resolve-DNSName` but without any additional command. This gives you the following handy oneliner

```
Get-ADComputer -Filter {Description -like "*$Description*"} -Properties Name, Description, IPv4Address
```

For more information about IPv4Address see [IPv4Address Attribute In Get-ADComputer](https://www.myotherpcisacloud.com/post/IPv4Address-Attribute-In-Get-ADComputer)